# Styling dialog presented via GoogleApiAvailability.showErrorDialogFragment independently of Activity

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-appcompat, android-theme, android-styles

### Background

I have an `Activity` with the following theme applied:

```xml
<style name="BlueTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/light_blue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/mid_blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/light_blue</item>
    <item name="dialogTheme">@style/BaseDialog</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/BaseDialog</item>
    ...
</style>
```

where the dialog theme is defined as follows:

```xml
<style name="BaseDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/light_blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/gray</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

The majority of the content of this screen is presented as white text on an all-blue background.

This `Activity` attempts to update the device security provider by invoking [`ProviderInstaller.installIfNeededAsync(this, this);`](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider.html#example_async). If this fails, I show a dialog using the following code:

```java
@Override
public void onProviderInstallFailed(final int errorCode, final Intent recoveryIntent) {
    final GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();

    if (googleApiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(errorCode)) {
        googleApiAvailability.showErrorDialogFragment(
                this,
                errorCode,
                ERROR_RESOLUTION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
```

Here's what that dialog looks like for one example failure:

[image]

This is a problem. The dialog title is white, so is not visible against the dialog background. Note that support alert dialogs displayed manually on other screens are correctly colored according to the `BaseDialog` style.

### Research So Far

The `Dialog` presented by calling `googleApiAvailability.showErrorDialogFragment` is constructed using an instance of `android.app.AlertDialog.Builder` rather than `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder`. Given this, my belief is that the colors of the platform dialog are being populated as follows:

- title from `BlueTheme.android:textcolor`
- message from `BlueTheme.android:primaryTextColor`
- button from `BlueTheme.colorAccent`

and are *not* populated using values from `BlueTheme.dialogTheme` or `BlueTheme.alertDialogTheme`.

I've been considering the following options for working around this issue:

1. Manually show a support alert dialog. Cons of this approach: no way to retrieve the custom per-error-code title/message that the built-in dialog would use (as far as I can tell);
2. Set `android:textColor`, `android:textColorPrimary` and `colorAccent` in `BlueTheme` to the values needed to obtain a correctly-colored dialog, then override these colors per-widget in XML layout files. Cons of this approach: ugly, lots of overriding needed;

Neither seem great. I also briefly investigated using a `ContextThemeWrapper` (no go, the `showErrorDialogFragment` method requires an `Activity` instance) and looked for a way to request that the Google Play Services dialog be constructed using a support `AlertDialog` builder (didn't find one).

### Question

Am I missing a more obvious approach to styling this dialog?

Comment: "button from BlueTheme.colorAccent" -- no, because that is not an `android:` theme attribute, so `android.app.AlertDialog.Builder` knows nothing about it. Another possibility is to start a `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` activity that launches the dialog, rolling you back to device default colors for that dialog (or, create your own theme based on `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` that customizes the colors of that dialog).

Comment: Ah, launching a new Activity to present the dialog sounds like a very promising option! I'll investigate that this morning, thanks :)

Comment: Ah, of course that restricts to e.g. holo dialogs on KitKat, which aren't customizable using styles/themes IIRC.

Comment: Definitely correct with respect to Holo on 4.x.

Comment: @stkent Could you tell me please how do you call this `onProviderInstallFailed()`?? How do you emulate outdated security provider?

Comment: @TotalAMD for testing purposes? I'm not sure there's an easy way. You could skip the provider install call and manually invoke the `onProviderInstallFailed` method with appropriate arguments dug up from source code to mimic a failure, but any recovery actions are likely to be nonsensical (as there's no actual issue to recover from).

Answer (score 4):

```
    GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int googlePlayServicesAvailableError = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    Intent errorResolutionIntent = googleAPI.getErrorResolutionIntent(this, googlePlayServicesAvailableError, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.DialogTheme);
    builder.setTitle("Title");
    builder.setMessage(ConnectionErrorMessages.getErrorMessage(this, googlePlayServicesAvailableError));
    builder.setPositiveButton(ConnectionErrorMessages.getErrorDialogButtonMessage(this, googlePlayServicesAvailableError), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            startActivityForResult(errorResolutionIntent, REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES);
        }
    });
    builder.setCancelable(false);

    if (!isFinishing()) {
        builder.show();
    }
```